# How to make python subprocess stop?

Tags: python

I am working on a program like `ping` in Linux.
The package sending program is just like that called count.py

```
import time
num = 0
while True:
    print num
    # send a package
    num += 1
    time.sleep(2)
```

And the GUI based wrapper is like that

```
import subprocess, signal, time, os

cmd = "python count.py"
P = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)

while True:
   time.sleep(5)  # GUI Pause button clicked
   os.kill(P.pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
   print "doing something"  # GUI Resume button clicked
   os.kill(P.pid, signal.SIGCONT)
```

But when I run the wrapper the output is like that.

```
0
1
2
doing something
3
4
doing something
5
6
7
```

I'm wondering dose the `wrapper.py` make the `count.py` pause? And if the system give a process that is being sleep for 10 seconds a signal of `STOP`, this process will wake up after 10 seconds?
Or there are some strategy to make the child process pause and resume?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
P.terminate()
```

To stop the subprocess. Or

```
P.kill()
```

To kill it.

It is all in the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate